# Beer Battered Onion Rings -- what makes them look shiny?

Tags: onions, deep-frying, restaurant-mimicry

I'm working on a  beer battered onion ring recipe and I think I have the recipe part but the onion rings look dull as they cool. I notice at restaurants etc...that they are usually shiny.

Is it an ingredient I'm missing (I keep thinking egg whites -- which I am not using)? or could it be the oil? I did not use peanut oil and I don't think my home fryer hold heat really well.

Right now the recipe is just flour, beer and seasonings (with the onions coated in flour before they are dipped). It's for a fund raiser so I really want to wow the patrons if possible.

Comment: Maybe you could, right after frying, coat the onion rings in egg wash and bake for a few minutes. Probably make them shiny but I doubt that is what restaurants do.

Answer (score 1):

The shininess is from oil that has seeped into your food. According to [About.com](http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/dryheatcooking/a/deepfrying.htm), the temperature at which oil starts to seep into food is around 163˚C (325˚F). You need to keep the temperature above that to prevent it getting shiny. Remember to use an oil with a high smoking point so you don't replace the shine with a carcinogen.

Answer (score 0):

The shiny part of the onion rings are the cooking oil. It really doesn't matter about how shiny your onion rings are though. Some restaurants deep fry theirs and the are more shiny than others. It all depends on how you cook them.

Comment: This doesn't make sense; if it were simply the cooking oil, all fried food, not to mention all *deep* fried food, would by shiny, and that certainly is not the case.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ The longer you cook them the more faded the shine is.